# Create a column of random integers, where the min and max integer for each row come from adjacent columns

Tags: r, random

I have a data frame:

```
letter <- c("A", "B", "C")
min <- c(1, 2, 3)
max <- c(4, 5, 6)
df <- data.frame(letter, min, max)
```

I want to add a 4th column to `df` which generates a random number for each row, where the lower and upper limits from which the random integers are sampled from are the `min` and `max` values of that row, respectively.

I have an inkling that I should use `sample()`, but when I do it returns a column of values drawn randomly from the referenced column:

```
df$random <- sample(df$max)
```

Could I also use `runif`?

Comment: What is `number`?  Your example throws an error.

Comment: Probably easiest in data.table once you fix your example.  `setDT(df)[, random := sample(min:max, 1), by = .I]`

Comment: Apologies, a mistake in editing, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe `df` as

```
   letter min max
1      A   1   4
2      B   2   5
3      C   3   6
```

I have a feeling there should be a better base R solution than this. However, for now we can try with `apply` and select (`sample`) any random number between the two columns.

```
df$third_column <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x[2]:x[3], 1))
df

#  letter min max third_column
#1      A   1   4            1
#2      B   2   5            4
#3      C   3   6            4
```

Comment: Works perfectly, despite my messed up example data, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can go the `dplyr` way:

`df %<>%
  rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(x = sample(min:max, 1))`